# ActiveRecord conditions across multiple tables.

Tags: activerecord, join, conditional-statements

I'm trying to retrieve cars from my database where each car has a manufacturer, and can have multiple styles.

For example, a ford fiesta is a coupe, sedan and hatch.

I've got my relationships set-up in my models, but now I want to create a query to return the results. The query construction will depend on what parameters are supplied.

This is what I've got so far

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:manufacturer_id] = params[:manufacturer_id] unless params[:manufacturer_id].blank? # this works!
conditions[:style_id] = "style_id IN (?)", params[:style_ids] unless params[:style_ids].blank? #this breaks it :(

cars = Car.find(:all, :conditions=> conditions)
return render :json => cars
```

The error getting returned is 
`PG::Error: ERROR:  column cars.style_ids does not exit` of course this is because the style_id is in a join table called `cars_styles`. Is there a way to tell ActiveRecord which table to look for within the condition?

The key thing here is that I want to only have one controller method which takes the params in existence and then creates the right query. So if I don't have a manufacturer_id, it will only query the styles, or if vice versa. Of course, I'll be adding other params later too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with scoped queries like this

```
scope :from_manufacturer, lambda{|manu|{:joins => :manufacturer, :conditions => "manufacturers.id = #{manu}" }}
    scope :from_style, lambda{|style|{:joins => :style, :conditions => "styles.id = #{style}"}}
    def self.get_cars(params)
        scope = self 
        [:manufacturer,:style].each do |s|

            scope = scope.send("from_#{s}", params[s]) if params[s].present?

         end
        scope
    end
```

Works great!